# How can I extrude these faces together?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I want to extrude these faces together to form a nose shape.
[image]

But when I do this with a subdivision modifier, the bottom four faces extrude seperately.
[image]

Comment: You somehow created internal faces while extruding. Try doing a merge by distance bevor you extrude.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by pressing the On Cage button in the subdivision modifer.
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).